# Google Chrome - JavaScript version

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

Which version of JavaScript does Google Chrome support in relation to Mozilla Firefox?  In other words, does Chrome support JavaScript 1.6, 1.7, or 1.8 which Firefox also supports or some combination of them?

Comment: As a sidebar, the language attribute of the script tag has been deprecated since the html 4 spec, it's recommended to use type attribute instead.

Comment: This is really weird, my plugin's js have issues with chrome, but working perfectly on other browsers. `onclick()` not working in `select-box`. i tried `onchange()`, `onblur()` , `onfocus()` but still not working in chrome.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

While Chrome will execute Javascript marked as "javascript1.7", it does not support JS1.7 features like the "let" scoped variable operator.

This code will run on Firefox 3.5 but not on Chrome using V8:

```
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript;version=1.7">
    function foo(){ let a = 4; alert(a); }; foo();
</script>
```

If you change language to "javascript1.7" and omit the type, it won't run with JS 1.7 features in Firefox 3.5.  The type section is necessary.

This seems to be related to a general WebKit bug, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23097; it may be that Chrome emulates the Safari behavior even though it uses a different engine.

[When asked about supporting JS 1.8 features](http://www.mail-archive.com/v8-users@googlegroups.com/msg00731.html), the V8 team said they were trying to track the version used in Safari so pages would act the same in both browsers.

Comment: That one with let is annoying. I'm forced to use nested closures instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake

Answer (score 18):

This thread is still relevant.  As of 2012, Chrome supports most of Javascript 1.6, not including string and array generics.  It supports none of 1.7. It supports reduce and reduceRight from 1.8, all of 1.8.1, and Getters and setters and all the non-version specific things listed on [this page](http://robertnyman.com/javascript/index.html). This page is linked from the Mozilla Developer Network, which specifies the versions of javascript, found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript).

Answer (score 14):

Google Chrome uses the [V8 javascript engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), which currently states that it implements ECMA-262, 3rd edition. This would imply it supports at least version 1.5.

Comment: Strange. I thought the `for(var i in objects)` iterator was something not in the third edition, yet it works fine in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @skerit by saying "it implements", at least all of the features in ECMA-262 v3 is available. They are free to add other features, including the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a simple Javascript 1.6 feature Chrome (and V8 users, like node.js) won't run: [for each … in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for_each...in)

```
for each (variable in object)
  statement
```

As it is JS 1.5 (per J c's answer) is the only version Chrome claims to completely implement.

In fact the Chrome team has mostly aimed for compatibility with Safari (most prominent Webkit user at the time), and refused features on those grounds.

Comment: Not supported in Chrome 16.0. Wasted an hour wondering why code was not working...

Comment: You're not using forEach correctly.  Check the syntax here: http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-1.6.html

Comment: @Sharon that's a different feature. My answer is framed by the question; I picked a JS 1.6 feature that is missing in Chrome. Link if you missed it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in#Syntax

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome supports up to Javascript 1.7:

```
<script language="javascript1.7">alert(1.7);</script> - Alerts
<script language="javascript1.8">alert(1.8);</script> - Doesn't alert
```

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing that will change over time- are we sure Chrome wont' support 1.8 by the time it leaves beta?  But upvote for showing how to check for yourself.

Comment: I'm sure it will support it *eventually* but I don't have any inside knowledge... possibly some Google employees are SO fans and could enlighten us.

Comment: @joel: That's too funny.  Have you ever seen a google product leave beta?

Comment: @Chris, Lol, you're right, I've been using gmail beta for years now. Search has left beta, I think, maybe...

Comment: Greg, your test isn't sufficient.  Chrome/V8 will run the code in the javascript1.7 section, but it didn't actually test JS 1.7 language features.  Those aren't supported in Chrome/V8.

Comment: Google had a purge of Beta markers recently. GMail isn't in beta, nor are most of their other major web apps.

Comment: I will point out that my current version of chrome still doesn't support things like Iterator or the yield keyword

Comment: This answer is not correct. Although V8 will run code in a javascript1.7 tag, it DOES NOT include any 1.7 specific features as of yet.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, however here goes. Google Chrome does not respond to the following

```
function foo(){
  let a = 4;
  alert(a);
}
foo();
```

hence it does not support JavaScript 1.7

Comment: there's a couple of other things i had trouble with in javascript 1.7 on chrome, like even accessing global variables and such