# JavaScript Iterators

Tags: javascript

I was going through MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) and came across [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

So naturally, I tried the snippets of code given in the page on Google Chrome v21.  To be specific, this code:

```
var it = Iterator(lang);
for (var pair in it)
  print(pair); // prints each [key, value] pair in turn
```

However, the console returns this error message:

```
ReferenceError: Iterator is not defined
```

Why's that?  Is the Iterator function deprecated or something? Am I missing a point?  Thank you for your help and time :-)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Google Chrome - javascript version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300185/google-chrome-javascript-version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=890):

> V8 is an implementation of ECMAScript, not JavaScript. The latter is a non-standardized extension of ECMAScript made by Mozilla.
>
> V8 is intended to be plug-in compatible with JSC, the ECMAScript implementation in WebKit/Safari. As such it implements a number of non-standard extensions of ECMAScript that are also in JSC, and most of these are also in Mozilla's JavaScript languages.
>
> There is no plan to add non-standard features that are not in JSC to V8.

Note: JSC stands for [JavaScript Core](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore) - the WebKit ECMAScript implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays have a built in map function that acts like an iterator.

```
[1,2,3].map(function(input){console.log(input)});
```

Standard Out:

```
1
2
3
```

Worst case you could easily design an iterator object, didn't full test this but if there are any bugs you should be able to quickly get this working.

```
var Iterator = function(arr){ return {
    index : -1,
    hasNext : function(){ return this.index <= arr.length; },
    hasPrevious: function(){ return this.index > 0; },

    current: function(){ return arr[ this["index"] ]; },

    next : function(){
        if(this.hasNext()){
            this.index = this.index + 1;            
            return this.current();
        } 
        return false;
    },

    previous : function(){
        if(this.hasPrevious()){
            this.index = this.index - 1
            return this.current();
        }
        return false;
    }
}   
};

var iter = Iterator([1,2,3]);

while(iter.hasNext()){
    console.log(iter.next());
}
```

Comment: Maybee   hasNext : function(){ return this.index < arr.length-1; }, ?

Comment: for object add   var arr= Object.keys(arr);

Answer (score 4):

`window.Iterator` AFAIK only exists in Firefox, not WebKit.

Answer (score 2):

```
var makeIterator = function (collection, property) {
    var agg = (function (collection) {
    var index = 0;
    var length = collection.length;

    return {
      next: function () {
        var element;
          if (!this.hasNext()) {
            return null;
          }
          element = collection[index][property];
          index = index + 1;
          return element;
        },
      hasNext: function () {
        return index < length;
      },
      rewind: function () {
        index = 0;
      },
      current: function () {
        return collection[index];
      }
    };
 })(collection);

 return agg;
};


var iterator = makeIterator([5,8,4,2]);

console.log(iterator.current())//5
console.log(  iterator.next() )
console.log(iterator.current()) //8
console.log(iterator.rewind());
console.log(iterator.current()) //5
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that Chrome v21 does not support that feature of JavaScript. It's part of the 1.7 spec. [Trying this](http://bclary.com/2004/08/27/javascript-version-incompatibilities#specver) might help for specifying explicitly 1.7 support in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For chrome you could use this

```
var someArray = [1, 5, 7];
var someArrayEntries = someArray.entries();
```

here is [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/The_Iterator_protocol), which you could find interesting