# Iterator for array

Tags: javascript

From [JavaScript Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079417/javascript-iterators)

```
var Iterator = function(arr){ return {
    index : -1,
    hasNext : function(){ return this.index <= arr.length; },
    hasPrevious: function(){ return this.index > 0; },

    current: function(){ return arr[ this["index"] ]; },

    next : function(){
        if(this.hasNext()){
            this.index = this.index + 1;            
            return this.current();
        } 
        return false;
    },

    previous : function(){
        if(this.hasPrevious()){
            this.index = this.index - 1
            return this.current();
        }
        return false;
    }
}   
};

var iter = Iterator([1,2,3]);
```

I want to rewrite this functionality through the addition of dynamic values

```
   added : function(data){
          arr.push(data);
          this.index++
        }


iter.added(1);
iter.added(6);
iter.added(7);
iter.added(8);
```

How do it ? 
I knows about iterator in ES 6 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Iterator but i want support IE

Comment: Remove the `this.index++` from `added` and it will work. Or doesn't it? Why not?

Comment: OK..... but i want when added then current index change

Comment: Ok, that's unexpected to me but go for it. Now what is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to implement [`next(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) similar to `.send` in python?

Comment: Btw, that `hasNext` method gives wrong results

Comment: Why should the index change after you add an item? Added items are put at the end of the array, so increasing the index causes you to skip items. And as Bergi already mentioned, `hasNext` doesn't work correctly - `arr.length - 1` is the last valid index, so there's only a next item when `index < arr.length - 1`. Also, `next` and `previous` return the current item on success - but an array can also contain falsy values, so you cannot distinguish between success and failure in that case. The code you have copied certainly has not been tested properly, as its author already said. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to add the `added()` function similar to what you posted, then update the initial value of index so the next() and previous() functions work. You'd need to set it to the input array length so the next() function knows you're at the last element.

```
var Iterator = function(arr){ return {
    index : arr.length,
    hasNext : function(){ return this.index < arr.length - 1; },
    hasPrevious: function(){ return this.index > 0; },

    current: function(){ return arr[ this.index ]; },

    next : function(){
        if(this.hasNext()){
            this.index = this.index + 1;            
            return this.current();
        } 
        return false;
    },

    previous : function(){
        if(this.hasPrevious()){
            this.index = this.index - 1
            return this.current();
        }
        return false;
    },

    added: function(x){
        arr.push(x);
      this.index++;
    }
}   
};

var iter = Iterator([1,2,3]);
console.log(iter)
iter.added(1);
iter.added(6);
iter.added(7);
iter.added(8);
console.log(iter)
console.log(iter.next())
console.log(iter.previous())
console.log(iter.previous())
console.log(iter.previous())
console.log(iter.previous())
console.log(iter.next())
console.log(iter.current())
```

Which outputs:

> Object {arr: Array[3], index: 3}
>    Object {arr: Array[7], index: 7}
>    false
>    8
>    7
>    6
>    1
>    6
>    6

Here it is in a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/8ojcrnkn/5/

Hope that helps!

Comment: What exactly did you change in the code? What do you mean by "declare `arr`", it already is declared?

Comment: You need to be able to access `arr` from the `added` function, so you'd need to add it, see line 2.

Comment: When I call iter.next() return 6 .... but I want then return false /// only support prev()

Comment: No, you don't. It's already accessible through closure, as it's a parameter of the `Iterator` function. Notice that you're not even accessing the `.arr` property anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: @bergi notice that its in the `added` function.  And without declaring it as a property its inaccessible by that function.

Comment: @AdamKonieska: Notice that it's also in the `hasNext` and `current` functions. And nowhere it is accessed as a property. You don't need that. You can directly access the variable. See [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572)

Comment: @zloctb: If you want the iterator to start at the end, you should make that `index: arr.length`

Comment: @zloctb actually you'd need arr.length+1 to be at the end of the array, so your `next()` function returns false.  I've updated the answer and fiddle with an example.  Hope that helps :-)

Comment: @AdamKonieska: Now with the cleanup you've destroyed the `current` method which should return the current element, not the current index. And `hasNext` should actually check for `this.index+1 < arr.length`, but that's wrong in the original code even.

Comment: I still insist on `this.index + 1` in `hasNext`, but the rest looks good now.

Comment: @Bergi with `this.index + 1` it goes out of bounds.  I think we want `this.index < arr.length-1` to check if we can move 1 position.

Comment: @AdamKonieska: `this.index+1 < arr.length` is equivalent to `this.index < arr.length-1`, yes, that's what we need.

Comment: @zloctb the example was updated.  I added the link to a fresh JS fiddle.  Hope that helps.